# Positive inner product of two covariances

Tags: covariance

What is the geometric interpretation for a positive inner product of two covariances?

$ Cov(X,Y) \cdot Cov(X', Y') > 0$.

Comment: In what sense is this an "inner product"?  You must be conceiving of the covariances as vectors--which is mathematically possible in several meaningful fashions--but exactly what way do you have in mind?